# PHP socket timeout & blocking

Tags: php, sockets

I am failing to understand how socket timeout and blocking works, and whether those two are interconnected.

This is my constructor:

```
public function __construct(Options $options)
{
    $this->connection = stream_socket_client($options->fullSocketAddress());

    stream_set_blocking($this->connection, true);
    stream_set_timeout($this->connection, 0, $this->timeout);
}
```

Reading from the manual, [socket timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) sets a timeout on a stream. My initial understanding was that the timeout was a limit up to which point the socket will try to do something, and after that will time out. The reality though, when checking also the socket status with `stream_get_meta_data()` that I get the following:

```
(
    [timed_out] =>
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] =>
    [stream_type] => tcp_socket/ssl
    [mode] => r+
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] =>
)
```

This is happening when I get the first response, for every subsequent response the `timed_out` value is `1`.

Since initially my timeout value was `1s` I thought the server was just slow to respond, but increasing the value to `50s` actually increased waiting time of each subsequent request as if the timeout was a mandatory waiting time, not the "up to" waiting time?

Also with regards to that I tried playing with socket blocking status. From the manual about [socket blocking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php) I couldn't get much info as it is not explaining what does it mean for a stream to be blocking or non blocking. Googling some resources, from what I could understand setting a socket to a blocking status would wait for server response, and only after the response got back, it would continue with other requests. I think that I didn't get that behaviour though.

Upon each write, I am doing a read. And writing seems to happen much faster independently of socket blocking.

```
public function send(string $xml)
{
    try {
        fwrite($this->connection, $xml);
        $this->options->getLogger()->logRequest(__METHOD__ . '::' . __LINE__ . " $xml");
        $this->checkSocketStatus();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->options->getLogger()->error(__METHOD__ . '::' . __LINE__ . " fwrite() failed " . $e->getMessage());
        return;
    }

    $this->receive();
}

public function receive()
{
    $response = '';
    while ($out = fgets($this->connection)) {
        $response .= $out;
    }

    if (empty($response)) {
        return;
    }

    $this->responseBuffer->write($response);
    $this->options->getLogger()->logResponse(__METHOD__ . '::' . __LINE__ . " $response");
}
```

Is there a way I can wait to check for response, and to make sure no subsequent request is made unless response is fetched? `sleep(1)` does the quick fix trick, but is not what I'm looking for. Calling the `receive()` function once again also does the trick to some extent, but the program starts behaving strange and I would like to avoid it:

```
    if (empty($response)) {
        $this->receive();
        return;
    }
```

Also, is there any interconnection between socket timeout and blocking status?